# Nikon P1000 wireless upload to PC

Tags: nikon, wireless, bridge-camera, snapbridge

How can I transfer photos wirelessly from the P1000 to my PC?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly. The P1000 uses Nikon's Snapbridge app (which is mobile-only) to configure wifi settings via Bluetooth, in order to transfer photos and control the camera *via the mobile device only*.

Using Snapbridge, the only hope of transferring files wirelessly to a PC is by using an Android device, and somehow using the device as a wireless bridge between the camera and PC. I have no idea if Android devices support this capability (whether *any* do, or just some), but I doubt it is supported out-of-the-box. I know certainly that Apple iOS devices do not support this functionality.

Comment: thank you scottbb, seems as tho Nikon has slipped backwards with this camera...

Comment: @rds it's not just this particular camera. Most of their Snapbridge-enabled cameras are this way. Not that I agree with their direction, but I assume it's because typical WiFi setup on cameras is so painful. Cameras don't have good interfaces to select arbitrary networks. It's been my experience that most cameras require the phone or PC to connect to the camera's network. Sucks from a user standpoint, but is understandable from the standpoint of the camera developers — fewer network types and security profiles (if any) to deal with.

Comment: thank you, I'm remembering p610 which I had a couple years ago and it worked nicely transferring direct to the pc!